# Can I get the compiler to fail compilation if a struct member is accessed before another one?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following struct:

```cpp
struct Result {
  bool success;
  union {
    float value;
    int error;
  };
};
```

The intention is that some function can return one of these structs to provide EITHER a return value or an error code, without resorting to exceptions.

```cpp
Result getValue() {
  if (somePrecondition) {
    return {.success{true}, .value{0.5f}};
  }
  return {.success{false}, .error{-1}};
}

auto r = getValue();
```

From this point, the caller CAN call `getValue()` and not use the result at all, but if they want to access either `.value` or `.error`, they MUST check `.success` at least once beforehand.

```cpp
std::cout << r.value;  // Not OK!
if (r.success) std::cout << r.value;  // Ok.
```

I could add runtime overhead by making everything private, adding `bool checked;` which gets set `true` when calling `.getSuccess();`, and having getters that throw exceptions or return "safe" values when `.checked == false`, but that all seems awful.

Instead, this strikes me as something the compiler can enforce.  Am I correct?  How do I ask it to do so?

Comment: use [std::expected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected), or a [c++11 library for it](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected)

Comment: Side not do NOT use "naked unions" in C++ : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c181-avoid-naked-unions. Unions come with a bunch of tricky conditions to use them right, so it is often safer to just use std::variant

Comment: `std::optional<std::variant<float,int>>` may also be an option. Where the optional part can be used to check if you got a valid answer and the variant bit can be used to hold either a float or an int

Comment: however to answer the question, no you cannot have the compiler raise an error at compile time, best thing you can get is a linter rule, but `std::expected` has a well-known interface, so you can expect people to use it well, misusing it is as bad as writing `int a = *(int*)nullptr;`, which you cannot prevent people from doing.

Comment: `std::expected` appears to be runtime-checked, and throws exceptions.  Otherwise it'd be great.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/libstdc++/api/a00086_source.html

Comment: There does appear to be a way to get a compiler to raise an error at compile time, for example [`static_assert()`](https://godbolt.org/z/3s38PMa4q).  The order of access of struct member variables is known at compile time, so it SHOULD be checkable at compile time, surely.

Comment: @AdamBarnes you can only check **constants** at compile time, the value of `success` is created at runtime, and there is always a way to get around any boxing you try to do, so just use something standard and hope the other programmers have basic understanding of standard C++, instead of inventing your thing and complain that they don't understand your thing.

Comment: Is `somePrecondition` a `constexpr` or `#define`, known at compile time?

Comment: @AhmedAEK I'm not looking to get the compiler to complain if `.success` is `false` at compile time, I'm looking to get it to complain if `.value` or `.error` are accessed before `.success` is accessed, _regardless_ of value.

Comment: @Eljay it is not, please see the previous comment.  I may need to clarify the question.

Comment: Basically what you seem to be asking is : When other developers use my code will they get a warning (preferably compile time) if they get any of the values before checking succes? Then no you cannot check this at compile time (unless you have some extra static code analyisis).

Comment: Document your API just like std::optional documents its api and state that getting a value for a "non-set" optional is just incorrect. At some point writing infrastructure to prevent misuse just adds (accidental) complexity to your system. ALso clients have a responsibility for reading documentation and writing unit tests too ;)

Comment: Change the code so that `value` or `error` can only be accessed through a public function, and that public function checks `success`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer you understand completely.  Yes, documentation is non-optional, I was just hoping there was some extra oven-gloving I could do.  The caller in this case is also going to be me, and I KNOW I'm stupid enough to forget sometime.

Comment: @Eljay please read the question - adding runtime overhead is not desired.

Comment: That is how you get the compiler to enforce it.  That's how you ask it to do so.

Comment: Inline setters and getters generally can be inlined, which minimises (with modern optimising compilers, eliminates) "runtime overhead".   And they do meet your requirement for a compilation error on trying to access data members directly.   Incidentally, have you done testing/profiling to justify your claim that you need to access the members with "no runtime overhead"??

Comment: @Peter if the requirement was to check the guarding boolean EVERY time that would be entirely correct, however the guard only needs to be checked at least once.